# Making a div scroll with the page when hitting either edge of the viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a floating box on the side of the page (Parent div) with a `position:sticky` child div that scrolls with the page when it hits the top of the viewport. https://codepen.io/Xanthippus480/pen/QWOydJe

What I would like to happen is for the child to be stuck to the top of the page when scrolling down but stuck to the bottom of the page when scrolling up i.e. to scroll when hitting either side of the viewport rather than simply being stuck to the top.

Is this something that can be done with purely html/css or would it require a script?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this approach - I've made updates to your **.Fbox-Div**.

Expand Code snippet to see how it works.

```css
.floating-box-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 1400px;
}

.floating-box {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  height: 1228px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #0077AE;
  background-color: white;
}

.Fbox-Div {
  position: sticky;
  width: 120px;
  /* max-height: 100%; */
  height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
  top: 2rem;
}

.PPR-Div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Book-In-Div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.Feedback-Div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.OOH-Div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.PPR-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Book-In-Button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.Feedback-Button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.OOH-Button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-box-wrapper">
  <div class="floating-box">
    <div class="Fbox-Div">
      <div class="PPR-Div">
        <a href="https://eghf.redatlas.co.uk/public/ppr?embedded=true">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/arbLHY0.png" title="PPR Form" alt="PPR" class="PPR-button" width="100px" height="100px"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="Book-In-Div">
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/alexf/Desktop/HTML/Contact.html">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dbNiH1J.png" title="Book In/Out" alt="Book-In" class="Book-In-Button" width="100px" height="100px"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="Feedback-Div">
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/alexf/Desktop/HTML/Contact.html">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/opqqn4C.png" title="Feedback" alt="Feedback" class="Feedback-button" width="100px" height="100px"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="OOH-Div">
        <a href="file:///C:/Users/alexf/Desktop/HTML/Contact.html">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZoCNpRV.png" title="Out-of-Hours" alt="OOH" class="OOH-button" width="120px" height="110px"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```